# MVC Windows Authentication prompts for windows credentials and ignores custom error configuration

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

In a web application, that runs MVC4 on an IIS7.5 server (integrated pipeline) using Windows Authentication and a custom role provider, I want to display a custom error page on 401 not authorized errors, if somebody tries to access something they do not have permissions for.

When I debug locally in Visual Studio, the error pages are displayed correctly, and my nice, custom "Not authorized" page shows up as expected.

Deploy to the server - and I get the windows prompt.

[image]

Here are the (I think) relevant parts of web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyCustomRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="FimOpsAccessControlRoleProvider" type="Namespace.MyCustomRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
      <error redirect="~/Error/Error401" statusCode="401" />
    </customErrors> 
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="401" />
      <error statusCode="401" path="/error/error401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

On the production server, I am able to browse to /error/error401 just fine - and I have also tried replacing that with a static html file and pointing to that, with the same result.

I have tried static error pages, doing stuff in global.asax Application_OnError, every thinkable combination of configurations I could think of in web.config - but with no luck. I have found at least 10 other posts on SO that deals with this problem, but none of the solutions work for me - maybe due to differences in versions, I do not know.

Why is this happening - and how do I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can override the behavior of browsers for Windows Authentication. This authentication happens by the web server **much before** your application code is ever reached. So IMHO putting custom error pages won't be of much help. If you want more control over the UI of those dialog boxes you might consider using a hybrid mode: Forms Authentication with an [`Active Directory Membership provider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the users. Now you have total control over the login srceens and what gets displayed in the event of a 401.

Comment: But is this really browser behavior, not the server/app? It works perfectly when run from Visual Studio - it is just when deployed to IIS it will not work.

Comment: The behavior of the Login box of an Integrated Windows Authenticated protected website is browser dependent.

Comment: I appreciate your answers, but this still bugs me. :) If it is a question of BROWSER behavior, not server behavior, why does it work when I run it locally (debug in visual studio)?

Comment: Which server are you using to run locally? Is it IIS Express? Did you enable Windows Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me nuts as well and after trying almost every possible combination I was able to get it to work by using the `responseMode="File"`. Like you I have a MVC site but could not get the `responseMode="ExecuteURL"` to work so the file I return simple redirects the user to the correct controller/action combo. Here is what I have in my web.config file:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="AuthRedirect.html" responseMode="File" />
</httpErrors>
```

And in my redirect file I just use the onload event to redirect. Adding text and a link would probably be smart as well:

```
<body onload="window.location = '/Account/Login'">
```